# Why isn't it possible to use placeholder syntax to multiply a map placeholder with itself?

Tags: scala

For instance, why can't you do the following?:

```
List(1, 2, 3).map(_ * _)
```

Yet it's possible to do:

```
List(1, 2, 3).map(x => x * x)
```

In this case, the result being a list of 1, 4, 9. I understand there are other methods of solving this particular problem, but I'm mainly just trying to understand why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each underscore refers to a new parameter, in order.
So `_ * _` is shorthand for `(x, y) => x * y` - not `(x, y) => y * x` or `x => x * x`.

`map` takes a function that maps a single value to a new value. So `_ * _` is incompatible with it.

Comment: Right, that makes a lot more sense. Would this still apply if you were to do something like, `print _` twice in a row?

Comment: @Seer Can you elaborate on your follow-up question? I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Sure thing. I understand this is again, a totally pointless example, if you do this: `List(1, 2, 3).map({ print _; print _; _ * 2 })`, why is the second, or third `_` not the second or third parameter?

Comment: @Seer I don't know the rules for all of the edge cases. If it isn't an extremely standard usage, use full lambda syntax with explicit parameter names. If it's not immediately clear to you what it means, it probably won't be to the next person reading your code either.

Comment: using `_` in place of a argument essentially "uses up" the argument and inserts it unnamed. If there are no more arguments to "use up" it's an error. `map` expects just one argument, so: boom, error.

Comment: @Seer: I believe (but cannot verify this at the moment) that in your example the first two underscores are not placeholders but η-expansion. Only the third underscore is a placeholder, and since `map` takes a `Function1`, that's correct. As always, you'll have to check the [Scala Language Specification](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/) to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

Because `map` operation takes just one parameter - you map one element. You would need to create operator which multiplies variable by itself